# MASM not taking input after first input

Tags: assembly, input, x86, x86-16, masm

Whenever I run this code, the program only takes the first input from me and then sends a garbage value in the 2nd input itself and then prints a totally random garbage value.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

.code 
main proc

mov ah , 1      ;input 1
int 21h

mov bl,al

mov al , 1        ;input 2
int 21h

add bl , al

sub bl , 48

mov dl , bl

mov ah , 2
int 21h

mov ah , 4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

I've tried changing the `mov al , 1` to `mov ah , 1` to take the input but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `mov al , 1` -> `mov ah , 1`

Comment: @MargaretBloom i did try that, it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an adder of two single digits.

[READ CHARACTER FROM STANDARD INPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm) doesn't wait for Enter.
Apparently when you tried **3** + **4** you pressed **3** **Enter** **4** **Enter** and your `;input 2` returned `0Dh` in AL, which is not the second decimal digit.

Try to press both digits without Enter, it should look like **347**.

You can omit the line `mov al , 1        ;input 2` completely, the interrupt doesn't clobber `AH=1` from previous input, but it overwrites AL with the second input character.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov al , 1      ;input 2
> int 21h
> ```

You got away with this typo on AL vs AH because the AH register still held the value 01h from before.

---

Although the pressing of <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each digit will indeed mess with the calculation in your program, it would also mean that you would be inputting that second digit and its accompanying <kbd>Enter</kbd> long after the program had terminated! The second digit would have appeared at the DOS prompt.

Example: <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
C:\>prog
♫
C:\>2
Bad command or Filename
```

My best guess is that you probably are **using the numeric keypad but without the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> lit**.
Under these circumstances, if you press eg. <kbd>1</kbd> it is actually <kbd>End</kbd>, and the DOS.GetKeyboardInputWithEcho function 01h will return a zero in AL and a second invokation of the same function will return the scancode also in AL.

Example: <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

```
C:\>prog
 O▼
C:\>
```

The 1st `int 21h` returns 0 and echoes a " "
The 2nd `int 21h` returns 4Fh and echoes an uppercase "O"
The program calculates 0 + 4Fh - 48 = 1Fh and displays "▼"
Without <kbd>NumLock</kbd> lit, <kbd>2</kbd> will actually be <kbd>↓</kbd> which does not show at the DOS prompt